# Confusing add command in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, addition, cmp

I was looking through some code and found 2 lines that perplexed me:

```
add    -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax
cmp    %eax,(%esi,%ebx,4)
```

I am accustomed to the standard `add src,dst` and `cmp x1,x2` and I'm not really sure what these lines are actually doing.

I believe that it is compiled with GCC

Comment: It would help if you edit the question to include more details about the specific assembler you're using. I don't recognize this syntax, though I must add, it's been a while since I've fiddled about with assembler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's using the Base + (Index * Scale) + Displacement addressing mode. At least, I think so. I'm not real familiar with the AT&T syntax. I think the Intel syntax would be:

```
add eax,[esi + ebx*4 - 4]
cmp [esi + ebx*4],eax
```

This looks like it's indexing into an array of integers (4-byte values). Imagine in C that you want to add the value from some array element to a total, like this:

```
int a[100];
int i = 10;
int total = 0;
total += a[i-1];
```

Now, make `esi` hold the address of the array, `ebx` hold the value of `i`, and `eax` hold the value 33. You'd get:

```
add eax,[esi + ebx*4 - 4]
```

The comparison instruction is testing to see if the result (in `eax`) is equal to the next value in the array. In the C example, that would be equivalent to comparing `total` to `a[i]`.

Comment: You are correct. AT&T syntax basics: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html