# Interpreting Assembly Code Comparison

Tags: memory, assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confusing add command in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159264/confusing-add-command-in-x86-assembly)

I would like to understand these two lines of Assembly:

```
8048d74:       03 44 9e fc             add    -0x4(%esi,%ebx,4),%eax
8048d78:       39 04 9e                cmp    %eax,(%esi,%ebx,4)
```

I think `(%esi,%ebx,4)` is an effective address of the form (BASE, INDEX, SCALE)

I believe the add command is taking the value at %eax, adding it to the value at [esi + ebx*4 + mem_location] and storing it in that same spot.

Then, the cmp instruction tests whether the value at [esi + ebx*4 + mem_location] is equal to the value at %eax.

So, this will return true only if one of the two values added is 0, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be AT&T format source code, in which the order is `op source, dest`. That means the first is adding the value at the effective address *to* eax. Then, the second line is comparing a second value to eax.